# Query RTC and NTP time in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, time, posix

The way the Linux kernel handle time is somewhat complicated as it uses different source of time, and regularly resynchronize everything. There are command-line tools (like `hwclock`) to query the RTC time explicitely. However I would like to do it programmatically, inside a C or C++ program. If Linux provides command-line tools, I assume that there is a way to do this programmatically, but so far I haven't been able to find the right function, and how to use it.

So my questions are:

- How to explicitly ask the system for the [RTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) time inside a C or C++ program? (ie what a `get_rtc()` function would look like?)
- How to explicitly ask the system for the [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol) time inside a C or C++ program? (ie what a `get_ntp()` function would look like?)

Comment: what keeps you from looking at the source of `hwclock` and `ntpq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [time(time_t*)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_time.htm) or [clock_gettime(clockid_t,struct timespec *)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) if you wish for more precision, from the [time.h header](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/time_h.htm) for the RTC time.

there is an [article describing how to get query NTP time](https://lettier.github.io/posts/2016-04-26-lets-make-a-ntp-client-in-c.html) ( which was a [google search](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=ntp+lib+c&oq=ntp+lib+c) away ).

describing the structure of an NTP packet

```
typedef struct
{

  uint8_t li_vn_mode;      // Eight bits. li, vn, and mode.
                           // li.   Two bits.   Leap indicator.
                           // vn.   Three bits. Version number of the protocol.
                           // mode. Three bits. Client will pick mode 3 for client.

  uint8_t stratum;         // Eight bits. Stratum level of the local clock.
  uint8_t poll;            // Eight bits. Maximum interval between successive messages.
  uint8_t precision;       // Eight bits. Precision of the local clock.

  uint32_t rootDelay;      // 32 bits. Total round trip delay time.
  uint32_t rootDispersion; // 32 bits. Max error aloud from primary clock source.
  uint32_t refId;          // 32 bits. Reference clock identifier.

  uint32_t refTm_s;        // 32 bits. Reference time-stamp seconds.
  uint32_t refTm_f;        // 32 bits. Reference time-stamp fraction of a second.

  uint32_t origTm_s;       // 32 bits. Originate time-stamp seconds.
  uint32_t origTm_f;       // 32 bits. Originate time-stamp fraction of a second.

  uint32_t rxTm_s;         // 32 bits. Received time-stamp seconds.
  uint32_t rxTm_f;         // 32 bits. Received time-stamp fraction of a second.

  uint32_t txTm_s;         // 32 bits and the most important field the client cares about. Transmit time-stamp seconds.
  uint32_t txTm_f;         // 32 bits. Transmit time-stamp fraction of a second.

} ntp_packet;              // Total: 384 bits or 48 bytes.
```

sending a query

```
// Call up the server using its IP address and port number.

if ( connect( sockfd, ( struct sockaddr * ) &serv_addr, sizeof( serv_addr) ) < 0 )
  error( "ERROR connecting" );

// Send it the NTP packet it wants. If n == -1, it failed.

n = write( sockfd, ( char* ) &packet, sizeof( ntp_packet ) );

if ( n < 0 )
  error( "ERROR writing to socket" );
```

reading the response

```
// Wait and receive the packet back from the server. If n == -1, it failed.

n = read( sockfd, ( char* ) &packet, sizeof( ntp_packet ) );

if ( n < 0 )
  error( "ERROR reading from socket" );
```

and parsing it

```
// These two fields contain the time-stamp seconds as the packet left the NTP server.
// The number of seconds correspond to the seconds passed since 1900.
// ntohl() converts the bit/byte order from the network's to host's "endianness".

packet.txTm_s = ntohl( packet.txTm_s ); // Time-stamp seconds.
packet.txTm_f = ntohl( packet.txTm_f ); // Time-stamp fraction of a second.

// Extract the 32 bits that represent the time-stamp seconds (since NTP epoch) from when the packet left the server.
// Subtract 70 years worth of seconds from the seconds since 1900.
// This leaves the seconds since the UNIX epoch of 1970.
// (1900)------------------(1970)**************************************(Time Packet Left the Server)

time_t txTm = ( time_t ) ( packet.txTm_s - NTP_TIMESTAMP_DELTA );
```

Comment: This is all "system"/"ntp" time; the user asked about the Real Time Clock ("RTC").  Some of these "hardware" clocks allow a limited number of writes so they are not 100% matched with the system time.

Comment: This is a better reference for Linux's `clock_gettime()` function, since it shows a ton more options for the `clockid_t` clock source type: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_gettime.3.html. The other reference, [linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime), unfortunately doesn't show nearly as much information for this function.

Answer (score 3):

A [**real-time clock (RTC)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) is a clock which keeps time relative to some absolute time epoch, such as [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which counts the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 at midnight UTC/GMT (sometimes written as `1970-01-01 UTC`), or [UTC time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) which I think is basically just Unix time but taking into account your local timezone, and displayed in your local *date and time* instead of in an absolute number of *seconds since 1 Jan. 1970*, like Unix Time. This is opposed to a regular clock which might count seconds since boot-up, for instance. Note that a real-time clock has *nothing to do* with a real-time operating system, which is a completely different concept.

In order to continue to keep time while a computer or system is unplugged, a real-time clock must have a backup battery, such as a tiny coin cell battery, to allow it to keep ticking while the system is without power.

Since real-time clocks keep time from a known epoch, you can use them to obtain the year, month, day, hour, minute, second, etc.

**"NTP" time** simply means: "Network Time Protocol (NTP)" time. This is a synchronization technique to periodically adjust each computer's local RTC so that they all read the same absolute time, at the same time. It takes real-time clocks to the next level of synchronization, since they can otherwise drift over time. NTP-adjusted RTCs can be within a few milliseconds of each other when on the same network (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). It also enforces leap seconds, which keep Unix Time and UTC time in-sync with the Earth's rotation around the sun, since that's how we arbitrarily define a year, but the orbit is not perfectly constant and the number of seconds that takes changes and drifts over time.

### How to read an NTP-adjusted RTC (Real-time clock) timestamp on Linux

So, to read the real-time clock on Linux you do the same thing you'd do to read the NTP time on Linux, since they are one and the same: the RTC is periodically adjusted according to the NTP synchronization is all.

Obtain such a timestamp with the POSIX/Linux function `clock_gettime()`, with the `CLOCK_REALTIME` clock chosen. See: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_gettime.3.html. It states (emphasis added):

> All implementations support the system-wide real-time clock, which is
> identified by `CLOCK_REALTIME`.  **Its time represents seconds and**
> **nanoseconds since the Epoch.**  When its time is changed, timers for a
> relative interval are unaffected, but timers for an absolute point in
> time are affected.

and:

> #### `CLOCK_REALTIME`
>
> A settable system-wide clock that measures real (i.e., wall-clock) time.  Setting this clock requires appropriate privileges.  **This clock is affected by** discontinuous jumps in the system time (e.g., if the system administrator manually changes the clock), and by the **incremental adjustments performed by `adjtime(3)` and NTP.**

Here is an example of getting an NTP-adjusted RTC timestamp in C or C++ on a POSIX or Linux system, with full error checking.

From my code [**timing_clock_gettime_full_demo.c**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/timing_clock_gettime_full_demo.c):

```c
// Obtain a timestamp
struct timespec ts;
int retcode = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
if (retcode == -1)
{
    printf("Failed to get a timestamp. errno = %i: %s\n",
        errno, strerror(errno));
}
```

Now, you have whole seconds stored in `ts.tv_sec` and whole nanoseconds from 0-999999999 (< 1 sec) stored in `tv.tv_nsec`.

You can print this in all sorts of ways. Here is the full, runnable code with a bunch of advanced printing demos. See the link just above for the full code online.

```c
// This define is required to bring in some of the extra POSIX features defined
// in `<time.h>`. Depending on your compiler settings, it may be required to
// get access to `clock_gettime()`. Using `-std=gnu17`, however, brings it in
// automatically since the compiler then uses the "gnu c" language instead of
// the standard "c" language.
//
// #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L

// Linux includes
// NA

// C includes
#include <errno.h>   // `errno`
#include <inttypes.h> // `PRIu64`
#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`
#include <string.h>  // `strerror(errno)`
#include <time.h>    // Includes `clock_gettime()` on Linux


#define NS_PER_SEC (1000000000L)
/// Convert seconds to nanoseconds
#define SEC_TO_NS(sec) ((sec)*NS_PER_SEC)


// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    printf("Obtain an NTP-adjusted Real-time Clock timestamp on Linux.\n\n");

    // Obtain a timestamp
    struct timespec ts;
    int retcode = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
    if (retcode == -1)
    {
        printf("Failed to get a timestamp. errno = %i: %s\n",
            errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    // Print seconds.nanoseconds
    printf("timestamp = %li.%09li sec.\n\n", ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);

    // Convert it to just `uint64_t` nanoseconds
    // See: eRCaGuy_hello_world/c/timinglib.c
    uint64_t ns = SEC_TO_NS((uint64_t)ts.tv_sec) + (uint64_t)ts.tv_nsec;
    printf("timestamp = %" PRIu64 " nanoseconds.\n\n", ns);

    // Convert it to a local time stored in `struct tm`. Use the re-entrant
    // (thread-safe) version of the function, called `localtime_r()`. See:
    // 1. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3p.html
    // 1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47532938/4561887
    // 1. `struct tm`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html
    struct tm localtime_struct;
    // Note: retptr means "return pointer"
    struct tm * retptr = localtime_r(&ts.tv_sec, &localtime_struct);
    if (retptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to convert to localtime. errno = %i: %s\n",
            errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    printf("localtime_struct contains:\n"
           "  ns    = %li\n" // Nanoseconds (0-999999999); NOT FROM THIS STRUCT
           "  sec   = %i\n"  // Seconds (0-60)
           "  min   = %i\n"  // Minutes (0-59)
           "  hour  = %i\n"  // Hours (0-23)
           "  mday  = %i\n"  // Day of the month (1-31)
           "  mon   = %i\n"  // Month (0-11)
           "  year  = %i\n"  // Year - 1900
           "  wday  = %i\n"  // Day of the week (0-6, Sunday = 0)
           "  yday  = %i\n"  // Day in the year (0-365, 1 Jan = 0)
           "  isdst = %i\n"  // Daylight saving time
           "\n",
           ts.tv_nsec,
           localtime_struct.tm_sec,
           localtime_struct.tm_min,
           localtime_struct.tm_hour,
           localtime_struct.tm_mday,
           localtime_struct.tm_mon,
           localtime_struct.tm_year,
           localtime_struct.tm_wday,
           localtime_struct.tm_yday,
           localtime_struct.tm_isdst);

    // Convert the `struct tm` localtime struct to a human-readable string in
    // normal human time units of Day, Month, Year, etc.
    // - This is the format string required to output timestamps in the exact
    //   same format as `git` uses when you `git commit`.
    const char * time_format_str = "%a %b %-d %H:%M:%S %Y %z";
    char time_str[100];
    size_t bytes_written = strftime(time_str, sizeof(time_str),
        time_format_str, &localtime_struct);
    if (bytes_written == 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to convert `struct tm` to a human-readable "
               "time string.\n");
    }
    printf("Formatted local time string = %s\n\n", time_str);


    return 0;
}
```

Sample build and run command, and output:

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu17 timing_clock_gettime_full_demo.c -o bin/a && bin/a
Obtain an NTP-adjusted Real-time Clock timestamp on Linux.

timestamp = 1650056712.080211270 sec.

timestamp = 1650056712080211270 nanoseconds.

localtime_struct contains:
  ns    = 80211270
  sec   = 12
  min   = 5
  hour  = 14
  mday  = 15
  mon   = 3
  year  = 122
  wday  = 5
  yday  = 104
  isdst = 0

Formatted local time string = Fri Apr 15 14:05:12 2022 -0700
```

### Use a system call or pipe

Keep in mind that you can also call *any* system call in C or C++ too, if you want. Meaning: any command-line call you can call by hand yourself in the terminal, you can call in C or C++ too.

So, if there is some system call that you can't find a C or C++ API to, just call it as a command-line system call.

The command is `system()`. I have an example of that here: [C equivalent of Python's exec() function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70285228/4561887).

If you need to read the output from the system call, you'll need to use a **pipe**, however. Here are the steps:

**How to read from a pipe** to read output from a system call in C:

1. Run a cmd and open a pipe with `popen()`.
2. Read the command response from the pipe with `fgets()`, using the file ptr to
   the pipe obtained from `popen()`.
3. Close the pipe file with `pclose()`.

For a demo of that, study my answer here: [Pipe demo: how to read keyboard presses from a system call pipe in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70979820/4561887).

### References:

1. My code above, in my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo: [**timing_clock_gettime_full_demo.c**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/timing_clock_gettime_full_demo.c)
2. [Retrieve Linux Time using struct timespec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47532938/4561887)
3. *****https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock_gettime.3.html
4. RTC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock
5. NTP: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol
6. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/localtime.3p.html - contains a great
   example of `strftime()` at the bottom too!
7. `struct tm`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ctime.3.html
8. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3p.html
9. My timing library

   1. [timinglib.h](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/timinglib.h)
   2. [timinglib.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/timinglib.c)

### See also

1. [my answer] [Retrieve Linux Time using struct timespec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71889097/4561887)